# selective flattening in python nested dictionary and finding keys

Tags: python, dictionary

i have the data in this format present in json file

```
 [
     {
        "FIRST NAME": "Nasim",
        "EMAIL": "ac@iaculisnec.net",
        "ADDLINE1": "855-8805 Nunc. Avenue",
        "CITY": "Masterton",
        "LOCATION":{"ADDLINE2":"855-8805",
                    "ADDLINE3":"Avenue",
                    "PIN":"100"}
      },
      {
        "FIRST NAME": "Xanthus",
        "EMAIL": "adipiscing.elit@tinciduntcongue.edu",
        "ADDLINE1": "357-4583 Curae; St.",
        "CITY": "Basildon",
        "LOCATION":{"ADDLINE2":"357-4583",
                    "ADDLINE3":"Curae; St.",
                        "PIN":"101"}
     },
     {
        "FIRST NAME": "Hedley",
        "EMAIL": "Quisque.libero.lacus@arcu.ca",
        "ADDLINE1": "315-623 Nibh. Road",
        "CITY": "Abingdon",
        "LOCATION":{"ADDLINE2":"315-623",
                    "ADDLINE3":"Nibh. Road",
                    "PIN":"102"}
   }]
```

this is my code

```
 data=json.loads(file('grade.json').read())
 for row in data:
      row['ADDRESS']= row['ADDLINE1']+','+ row['CITY']
      del row['CITY'], row['ADDLINE1']
      row['LOCATION1']=row['LOCATION']['ADDLINE2']+','+row['LOCATION']    ['ADDLINE3']+','+row['LOCATION']['PIN']
      del row['LOCATION']
 data =json.loads(file('grade.json').read())
 out = {}

 for sub in data.values():
      for key, value in sub.items():
          if key in out:
              del out[key]
          else:
              out[key] = value

 print(out)

 file('files','w').write(json.dumps(data))
 out_path= "outfile9.csv"
 fieldnames = list(set(k for d in data for k in d))
  with open(out_path, 'wb') as out_file:
     writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, dialect='excel')
     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerows(data)
```

i want to remove d nested dictionary(LOCATION1, here after formatting-previously was LOCATION) but retain ADDLINE2,3,PIN as the same. i want a flattened dictionary. what can i do to  improvise it?

i require keys in this form
**[firstname,email,address,location{addline2,addline3,pin}]**
even if extra nested values are added it should dynamically appear in this form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 data=json.loads(file('grade.json').read())
 for row in data:
      row['ADDRESS']= row['ADDLINE1']+','+ row['CITY']
      del row['CITY'], row['ADDLINE1']
      row['LOCATION1']=row['LOCATION']['ADDLINE2']+','+row['LOCATION']    ['ADDLINE3']+','+row['LOCATION']['PIN']
      del row['LOCATION']
 data =json.loads(file('grade.json').read())
```

the above is all useless because of the last line, resets data.
to flatten ADDLINE2,3,PIN , add in the above loop, before everything else

```
row['ADDLINE2'] = row['LOCATION']['ADDLINE2']
row['ADDLINE3'] = row['LOCATION']['ADDLINE3']
row['PIN '] = row['LOCATION']['PIN ']
```

Comment: how to get nested dictionary keys only?

Comment: @Shadow you are invited to ask another more specific question

Comment: i can access the nested keys individually,for eg: if i give row['LOCATION'] i will get the sub-keys of that key. but when i give row.keys() i will get only the outer keys and not the inner keys which are in d location. to get all the outer and inner keys at a go how can i write it.the format which i need is  [firstname,email,address,location{addline2,addline3,pin}] . even if there are extra subkeys it should be displayed automatically